# Libgdx - TMX map not rendered

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am making a 2D Android game.  The problem is that my tiled game map is not rendered, although my GUI class is just fine. It looks like `renderer.render()` is never called.

Here is screen shoot from my phone.

[image]

It should render this tiled map, but it doesn't.
[image]

Main.class:

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter implements Screen {
    private ZombieGame game;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport gameView;
    private GUI gui;
    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    public Main(ZombieGame game){
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        gameView = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);

        gui = new GUI(game.batch);

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("level1.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        camera.position.set(gameView.getWorldWidth() / 2, gameView.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void show(){

    }

    @Override
    public void hide(){

    }

    @Override
    public void create () {

    }

    public void keyEvent(float dt){
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            camera.position.x -= 100 * dt;
            System.out.println("COORD: " + camera.position.x);
        }
    }

    public void update(float dt){
        keyEvent(dt);
        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.render();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gui.stage.getCamera().combined);
        gui.stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

ZombieGame.class:

```
public class ZombieGame extends Game{
    public SpriteBatch batch;

    @Override
    public void create(){
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        setScreen(new Main(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render(){
        super.render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details as to what the program is suppose to do?

Comment: I added a image of that tiled map.

Comment: Fixed typos and minor mechanical problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use in **setToOrtho()** method in create(),

```
   camera.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Instead of FitViewport,

```
gameView = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
 camera.position.set(gameView.getWorldWidth() / 2, gameView.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
```

Just give a try and let me know. Thanks...